# PHP Form not posting the submit button correctly

Tags: php

I was doing an application form and the form is not working. When I click the submit button it doesn't even run the if statement to POST the variables.
My form tag looks like this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

My submit button looks like this:

```
<button name="submeter" type="submit" class="btn btn-gfort">Submeter</button>
```

And the **if** statement in my form looks like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submeter'])) {
```

I even tried to run a JS alert just to see if it actually enters the if statement but it doesn't. No console errors as well.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: your question has very poor information please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
And add more information in your question

Comment: Try using it like this 

<input type="submit" value="Submit">

Comment: Do u put the button type='submit' before the /form

Comment: Submit input also doesn't work @shammidevd.

Comment: Yes, i do have my submit button before the closing form tag. @Weber

Comment: add the action on form tag and have a try

Comment: Didn't work, I'll probably try to use another file with the action tag.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added `method="post"` to the `<form>`-tag?

Answer (score 1):

Well your codes looks fine. it seems you are submitting the form using post method on some php file. Please share the complete form element and the codes of the target file that you have defined in the action attribute of form tag.
the submit button sends the data to server and there you can process the data using any server side scripting language.  your codes must look something like

```
<form action="process.php" method = "post">
<!-- your form controls -->`
<button name="submeter" type="submit" class="btn btn-gfort">Submeter</button>
</form>
```

then create another file on same location where html/php file containing this form is saved with name process.php, in which you can use following codes.

```
if(isset($_POST['submeter'])) {
// php codes
}
```

in case you want to subimt the form on the same page. make sure your file is php use action="#" in form tag and place the file of your webserver as you can not run php files directly from your filesystem but you need to run it through your webserver

Comment: I'm doing everything on the same page, that's why I don't use the action attribute. What do you mean by method="#"? I'm already using method="post". Also I thought the form didn't matter much because it's not what's causing the issue which is why I didn't share it.